# EF Core ExecuteUpdate can write lile EFCore.BulkExtensions BatchUpdate method

Tags: entity-framework-core

In my project, I use EFCore.BulkExtensions for batch updates (https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions)

BulkExtensions code is written like this :

```
context.Items.Where(a => a.ItemId <= 500)
             .BatchUpdate(a => new Item { Quantity = a.Quantity + 100 });
```

In EF Core 8:

```
context.Blogs
       .Where(b => b.Rating < 3)
       .ExecuteUpdate(setters => setters.SetProperty(b => b.Rating, b => b.Rating + 1));
```

I do not want to use bulk extensions, so how can I switch to a new way of writing without affecting the code wrote before? (change `BatchUpdateAsync` to EF Core's `ExecuteUpdate`)

I am not good at expression, is there any method that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar:

```cs
context.Items
  .Where(a => a.ItemId <= 500)
  .ExecuteUpdat(setters => setters.SetProperty(a => a.Quantity, a => a.Quantity + 100));
```